# How to loop through an array of strings Gatling during scenario building

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm trying to loop through an array of products (Strings) in order to execute a call for each of them but I'm mismatching some types during scenario building, here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
  val createAddToCart: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Add to cart").exec(CartRequest.addToCart())
```

This is my CartRequest object:

```
  def addToCart(): Unit (???) = {
    for (product <- products) {
      addToCart(product)
    }
  }

 def addToCart(productId:String): ChainBuilder =
  {
    exec(http("addToCart")
      .post(addToCartUrl)
      .headers(authHeaders)
      .body(generateRequestBodyForProduct(productId)).asJson
      .check(bodyString.saveAs("body"))
    ).exec(
      session => {
        body = session("body").as[String]
        println("response body " + body)
        session
      }
    )
  }
  def generateRequestBodyForProduct(productId: String): Body with (Expression[String]) =
    {
        StringBody("{ \"productId\":  \"" + productId + "\"," +
          " \"qty\": " + 1 + " , " +
          "\"storeId\": \"" + storeId + "\"}")
    }
```

Obviously, I'm having problems calling CartRequest.addToCart() due to type mismatching (Unit to ChainBuilder).
Is there a way to execute and return the addToCart method as a list of scenarios?
I hope I explained myself well.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't look like a Scala developper. You should probably use the new Java DSL available since Gatling 3.7.

Then, you're not using the Gatling constructs properly.

- your `for` loop should be a Gatling [foreach](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/#foreach) instead
- the dynamic `productId` in your request body should be resolved with [Gatling Expression Language](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/el/) => `"{ \"productId\":  \"#{productId}\", \"qty\": " + 1 + " , " + "\"storeId\": \"" + storeId + "\"}"`

Comment: I am absolutely not a Scala developer :), I'm used to Java so I'm having troubles. Thanks for your response. I'll post a solution that I made with foreach loop

Comment: Then, you should definitely switch to Gatling Java :) This way, you'll also be able to tell appart struggles with the programming language and struggles with the Gatling idioms.